# Android TextView show just above the Menu

Tags: android, menu

i have a textview at the bottom of my screen but when menu clicked, i need to move the textview just above the menu, so that every one can see the textview,now when i clicked menu ,it cover the textview ,any solution for this problem

Comment: What do you mean by "show a text always above the menu"?

Comment: @CommonsWare: He wants to have the TextView automatically move/remain above the menu overlay.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with the virtual keyboard, I think.

It would not be a good idea anyway, since menus are for things the user can decide to do without looking at the screen information. Menus should be self-explaining.

A dialog is another story, since it sometimes refers to items, which are covered by it (open file e.g.). One might want to repeat the item in the dialog. I would not use a menu to open a file, the user has selected from a view. Instead, I would use a popup dialog, repeating the file name.